# What is the request object exactly of the source callback?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

The Source callback of the autocomplete function takes an request and a response object as parameters. I couldn't find any useful information for what these object excatly are and what properties and methods they define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to understand what is `function(request, response) {...}` is to go through the source code of the plugin itself.

I'll try to be as clear as possible, tell me if you need more details or explanations.

### **1. What is "source"**

When you enter some value in the input, the plugin executes a "search" through the private method "_search"

```
_search: function(value) {
    this.pending++;
    this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");

    this.source({ term: value }, this.response);
}
```

Reading the last line, you can see the plugin expects the **"source"** property to be a **function** that it executes passing as

- **request**: an object-literal with one property `term` which will contain what was entered in the input
- **response**: the plugin property `response`. This property is a function that by default calls the private method "_response" which is responsible for showing the menu, filtering the list, closing the menu etc.

---

### **2. Using the "source" option**

But reading the documentation, the `source` option accepts an array or an url for remotely getting the values... so how does this work ?

The plugin initialize `this.source` through the private method `_initSource`:

```
_initSource: function() {
    var self = this,
        array, url;
    if ($.isArray(this.options.source)) {
        array = this.options.source;
        this.source = function(request, response) {
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
        };
    } else if (typeof this.options.source === "string") {
        url = this.options.source;
        this.source = function(request, response) {
            if (self.xhr) {
                self.xhr.abort();
            }
            self.xhr = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                autocompleteRequest: ++requestIndex,
                success: function(data, status) {
                    if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
                        response([]);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    } else {
        this.source = this.options.source;
    }
},
```

You can see that in both cases the plugin ends up defining `this.source` as `function(request, response) {...}`

- if you provide an array, it executes the `response` method to display the menu passing a filtered array using `request.term`:

  ```
  this.source = function(request, response) {
      response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
  }
  ```
- if you provide an url, it makes the ajax request and upon success, executes the `response` method to display the returned `data`:

  ```
  success: function(data, status) {
      if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
          response(data);
      }
  },
  ```
- otherwise, it uses the provided option value as it is

---

### **3. When passing a function(request, response) as "source" option value**

So when you call the plugin this way:

```
$(...).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) { ... }
});
```

You're actually not providing the plugin with any data !

But you have the opportunity to gather the data the way you want (other that an array or an url), and still have access to the plugin functionnality through the parameters. You have the input content through `request.term` and you can execute the `response` callback to display the results.

**Example ? The Autocomplete demo pages...**

If you go to the [Autocomplete Multiple values](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) demo page, the jquery ui team uses this functionnality.

The data is stored in a javascript array `var availableTags = [...];`

And they define the `source` option this way:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
}
```

1. Filter the `availableTags` array with a special treatment for handling multiple values in input
2. call the `response` function to display the filtered array