# jQuery autocomplete get id

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

There is a demo that works very well. http://jsfiddle.net/salman/VaKfP/

But I got some problems while following the sampled code.

```
<script>
var js = '<?php echo $json; ?>';
console.log(typeof js);
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(js);

    //local = [{value:1, label: "c++"},{value:2, label: "java"},{value:3, label: "ruby"},{value:4, label: "rubyonrails"}];

    $("#nominee_input").autocomplete({
          source: arr,
          focus: function(event, ui){
                 $('#nominee_input').val(ui.item.name);
                 return false;
          },
          select: function(event, ui){
                 $('#nominee_input').val(ui.item.name);
                 $('#hidden').val(ui.item.uid);
                 return false;
          }
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
          alert($('#hidden').val());
    });

});
</script>
```

The $json variable is JSON type, its format is like: [Object { uid="11443624", name="angela"}, Object { uid="21503235", name="Sunny Lee"} ].

If I change the source to **local**, it works very well. But it doesn't work when I use **arr** as source.

Need your help. Thanks.

Comment: In the interest of best practice, you might want to make the slight change of 'local = ...' to 'var local = ...' in the commented line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the arr variable format is really `[{ uid="11443624", name="angela"}]` the `=` is your issue. Make certain your php is formatting the object correctly. You shouldn't need to run parseJSON on it if you format it right. The php output should be formatted with label/value pairs like you have in the local example `{value:1, label: "c++"}`. Autocomplete won't recognize uid/name pairs unless you override the renderItem method as per [the ui example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data).

```
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: projects,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
                $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
                $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

                return false;
            }
        })
        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is probably the format of variable. Do you know how to change the code to render the right names when I type in some letters? I tried Didier's code, but it seems not working properly. The code is `.append( $('<a></a>').attr('data-uid', item.uid).text(item.name) )`

Comment: Actually I've used console.log(arr) and console.log(local) to check the difference of arr and local, but it seems that they're the same type...

Comment: what is the actual output of console.log(arr)?

Comment: console.log(arr): `[Object { uid="11123432", name="Shen Wang"}, Object { uid="21545263", name="Siwen Chen"}, Object { uid="324785670", name="Suleng Soeung"}, Object { uid="49723430", name="Di Zhao"}, Object { uid="936543247", name="Yumin Lu"}, Object { uid="507789969", name="Sebastian Mitre"}]`  ---------- console.log(local): `[Object { value=1, label="c++"}, Object { value=2, label="java"}, Object { value=3, label="ruby"}, Object { value=4, label="rubyonrails"}]`

Comment: I figured it out. I just rebuilt the arr, changed the names of properties from `uid` and `name` to `value` and `label` as the plugin seems to only support the two property names.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a **label** or **value
>   property** or both

The autocomplete plugin expects as source an array of objects with the properties: **label** or/and **value**

You variable `js` is not suitable for this:

1. the syntax is incorrect. An array of objects should be defined this way: `[{key1: 'key1', key2: 'key2'}, ...]`
2. you cannot use $.parseJSON() as it is not a json object but an array. Just output your php like this:

   ```
   var js = <?php echo $json; ?>; // $json being [{uid:"11443624",name:"angela"},...]
   ```

---

When autocomplete makes a search based on the input, it uses the `source` option. Internally, the plugin actually expects the `source` option to be a function to execute. The trick is that when you specify an array or an url, the plugin creates a wrapper around it to be able to use it (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837292/123127)).

If you have a custom data source, you can pass yourself the `source` option as the expected function. It is of the form:

```
source: function(request, response) { ... }
```

The request parameter contains one property `request.term` which is the text entered in the input, the response parameter is a function to display the menu with the suggestions. Use it like this:

```
$("#nominee_input").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {

        // $.map() builds an array understandable by autocomplete
        // $.ui.autocomplete.filter() will filter the array based on the request.term
        var filteredData = $.ui.autocomplete.filter($.map(arr, function(item) {
            return {
                value: item.name,
                label: item.name,
                uid: item.uid
            };
        }), request.term);

        // use the response callback to display the results
        response(filteredData);

    }
});
```

**Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8RPA8/)**

---

When you have a specific data source (with other properties than label and value), you might wan't to display the results in a custom manner. For this you can't override the default `_renderItem` method of the autocomplete plugin:

```
$("#nominee_input").autocomplete({ ... })
    .data("autocomplete")
    ._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
       return $( "<li></li>" )
           .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
           .append( $('<a>' + item.label + ' - ' + item.uid  + '</a>')
                          .attr('data-uid', item.uid)
           )
           .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It starts working but still has some problems. When I enter a letter 'e', it shows many answers that are not relevant to 'e'. If I choose one name from the scroll menu, I can get the id. Nice. But I tried other letter, it seems not working.

Comment: `.append( $('<a></a>').attr('data-uid', item.uid).text(item.name) )` What does this mean, especially `data-uid`?

Comment: It is a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). It is a feature of HTML5 (but usable with previous version as they are just attributes). It allows storing data relative to an element in html attributes. Note: it has no specific purpose in autocomplete plugin actually.

Answer (score 0):

`$.parseJSON` returns an object, but it looks like that autocomplete uses an array for the `source` parameter. Have you tried directly using that `js` variable for the `source`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$("#nominee_input").autocomplete({
    source: <?php echo $json; ?>, /* without '' ! */
    ...
```

?

Can you write what "echo $json" writes exactly ?

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work. I think it might be the format problem of JSON and array (variable: local). But I tried many possible ways, not working...